# PHP can not connect to Database

Tags: php, mysql

Mysql Version 5.1.73

I am able to connect to the mysql database from the shell with this commmand

```
mysql -u medit_login -p
```

I enter my password and I receive the welcome to the MySQL monitor.

```
Your MySQL connection id is 5 
Server version 5.1.73 Source Distribution.
mysql>
```

When I try to login from php I receive cannot connect to Database.

I have tried many times to give permissions with this command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on markdb.* TO 'medit_login'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

Is version 5.1.73 looking for an encryption password?

Comment: That version of MySQL is a bit long in the tooth! I think Methuselah was using that when he was a boy

Comment: Since we can't see your PHP connection code, and you didn't tell us the exact error message, and we don't know the network topology, we can't really comment. But yeah...time you upgraded your mysql server anyhow.

Comment: SHow us the PHP code you are using. Then maybe we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was firewall the port was after the reject and that was the reason of failure.